# Finding all sequences (and the longest sequence) of a value in an numpy arra

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a case where I need to find the optimal distribution of a number of items with the value of `1` in an numpy array. Let's say that I have the following array that only contains `0`s and `1`s in a random order:

```
import numpy as 

# this 1d array can have up to 10000 elements

data = np.array([
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
])

num_of_ones_to_fill_gaps = 5
```

Additionally,  I have an amount of `n` `1`s (`num_of_ones_to_fill_gaps`) that should be distributed in the array in a way, that the longest possible, coherent sequence of `1`s is built. Using `num_of_ones_to_fill_gaps=5` (five `1`s can be used for filling up the gaps with `0` values), there are for example 3 results which all have a longest sequence of `1`s with a sequence length of `11`.

```
        a)                           b)                       c)
result = np.array([    |    result = np.array([    |  result = np.array([ 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,   |    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,   |  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
                                                                     ^  ^
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,   |    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,   |  0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
                                                      ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,   |    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,   |  1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
                                                      ^  ^
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,   |    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,   |  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
            ^  ^  ^    |             ^  ^  ^  ^    |   
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,   |    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,   |  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^    |    ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^    |   
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,   |    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,   |  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
^                      |                           |   
])                     |    ])                     |  ])
```

My first question would be if there is a chance that numpy provides a built-in **vectorized** method that is capable of calculating the longest possible sequence of `1`s and returns me a start and end index of the (multiple) same length results?

```
result = np.array([
(22, 32),
(21, 31),
(5, 15),
])
```

My second question would be if there exists a numpy **vectorized** method, that extracts **all** the possible sequences of `1`s (with filled gaps), no matter what length they have. The result might look something like:

```
result = np.array([
(0, 4),  # data[0:4], data.size == 5
(1, 6),  # data[1:6], data.size == 6 because index at position 5 is a 1
(2, 7),  # data[2:7], data.size == 6 because index at position 5 is a 1
(3, 9),  # data[3:9], data.size == 7 because indices at position 5 and 8 are a 1
...
])
```

I tried to outline the problem in an understandable way. I did reasearch in the docs and stackoverflow but don't know how to start. What I've found are iterative solutions. Any suggestions and solutions are highly appreciated. Thank you once again!

Comment: When you distribute the 1s, are you constrained to place them in order in the array? I.e. once I have placed the first one, am I constrained to place the others in the first free spots after the first one?

Comment: That's a very good question ... As far as I can tell you right now - no - as long as they are placed in a way that they contribute to forming the optimal/longest sequence of ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my current solution, assuming that I can fill the ones in any combinations in the free spots (i.e. the zeros).

Disclaimer: I did not test it extensively.

```py
from itertools import combinations

import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import find_objects
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import label


data = np.array(
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,]
)
m = len(data)

num_of_ones_to_fill_gaps = 4

# Find all possible combinations of indexes which we could set to 1
zero_idxs, = np.where(np.equal(data, 0))
combs = list(combinations(zero_idxs, num_of_ones_to_fill_gaps))

# Convert combinations into one-hot vectors; the len of each vector
#  is equal to the len(data)
combs_onehot = np.eye(m)[np.asarray(combs)]

# Summing on the first axis will give us masks that we can directly
#  sum to the original array. For example, if we had two 1s to insert
#  and a possible combination were (0, 1), combs_onehot would become
#  ([1, 0, 0, ...], [0, 1, 0, 0, ...]) and summing would give us the
#  mask [1, 1, 0, 0, ...]
masks = np.sum(combs_onehot, axis=1).astype(int)

# Broadcast sum of the mask to original array. If our original array
#  had len M and we found N possible combinations, this has shape (N, M)
data_filled = data + masks

# 1-D connected component labeling
str_el = np.asarray([[0,0,0], [1,1,1], [0,0,0]])
labeled, _ = label(data_filled, structure=str_el)

slices = find_objects(labeled)

longest = max(slices, key=lambda x: x[1].stop - x[1].start)
longest_row = longest[0].start

print(f'Best solution: {combs[longest_row]}')
print(f'Longest run: {longest[1].stop - longest[1].start}')
```

Comment: Oh, this is a nice solution. Thank you! Seconds ago, I've found another solution at https://gist.github.com/alimanfoo/c5977e87111abe8127453b21204c1065. Still I couldn't find a nice way to distribute the five `1`s in an optimal way. Anyway, thank you for your help and if no one comes up with another suggestion, I'm more than happy to accept your answer.

Comment: @hetsch This problem totally hooked me - I just edited my solution with a more complete answer

Comment: Brilliant! For what I can say now, this seems to be the solution. Also much cudos for the comments, they help a lot. I have to dig into what's really going on under the hood but this gives me tons of ideas to play with! Very, very happy  that you got hooked by the problem :)

Comment: When you should be writing the PhD thesis, there's nothing easier than get hooked by random things that you encounter during the day! :D